# How should I get access to a custom view that is in a fragment layout?

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment whose layout consists of a custom view (`MyCanvasView`) and a button. I am trying to access a variable through a getter method in the `MyCanvasView` class. I am able to access the button to make an `OnClickListener`, but trying to access the custom view the same way doesn't work. `vMapView` remains `null`. How can I get access to the custom view from the fragment that contains it?

In fragment java file:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_anchor, container, false);

    Button btnSubmitAnchor = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit_anchor);
    MyCanvasView vMapView = (MyCanvasView) v.findViewById(R.id.anchor_selection_view);

    btnSubmitAnchor.setOnClickListener((view) - > {

        receivedAnchor = vMapView.getTempAnchor();
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Received anchor:\n" + receivedAnchor.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "no anchor was received");
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

In MyCanvasView.java:

```
public Anchor getTempAnchor() {
    return tempAnchor;
}
```

In select_anchor.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <view
        android:id="@+id/anchor_selection_view"
        class="com.decawave.argomanager.ui.view.MyCanvasView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit_anchor"
        style="@style/MtrlBorderlessButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_submit_anchor" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try thus way:

```
<com.decawave.argomanager.ui.view.MyCanvasView

    android:id="@+id/anchor_selection_view"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue. `vMapView` remains null after its initialization in the fragment java file. Does declaring the UI element this way work differently than explicitly declaring the class as I had done?